# Why does Save As say it's looking for a file in the windows system folder instead of my actual file path?

Tags: excel, vba

It was working before, and saving a password protected file to an email attachment. Now suddenly it says it's looking for a file in the system folder when the path is a simple folder in my local documents

[image]

```
Sub FY23_PWProtectCompFile()

Dim i As Integer
Dim chapterComp As Workbook
Dim emailList As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim pw As String
Dim chapter As String
Dim rows As Integer
Dim subj As String
Dim attachment As String
Dim chapterFile As Workbook


Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.createitem(0)
    Set myAttachments = outlookmailitem.Attachments

Set chapterComp = Workbooks.Open("I:\Calendar 2023\2023 Budget\2023 Misc. Budget Info\blahblah.xlsm")
Set emailList = chapterComp.Sheets("EmailList")
Set rng = emailList.Range("B1:Z1000")

Workbooks.Open ("I:\Calendar 2023\2023 Budget\2023 Misc. Budget Info\blahblah.xlsm")
emailList.Activate

rows = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To rows
    chapter = Range("B" & i).Value
    email = Range("H" & i).Value
    pw = Range("I" & i).Value
    
    Set chapterFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\blah\Documents\Chapters\" & chapter & ".xlsx")
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\blah\Documents\Chapters\" & chapter & ".xlsx")
    
    
    chapterFile.SaveAs Password:=pw
    
        outlookmailitem.To = email
        outlookmailitem.cc = ""
        outlookmailitem.bcc = ""
        outlookmailitem.Subject = chapter & " Compensation"
        outlookmailitem.body = "A copy of your compensation budget is attached!"
           
        attachment = chapterFile.Name
            
        myAttachments.Add (attachment)
        outlookmailitem.display
        'outlookmailitem.send

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Side note, but as commented yesterday, why are you opening the workbook twice?

Comment: `myAttachments.Add` needs the *full path* of the file, as was also commented yesterday.

Comment: Thank you Ben. Yes, I did make that suggested change yesterday, but reverted once it stopped working, and forgot to remove the second open. So to make the full path adjustment you're talking about, I need to change it to attachment = chapterFile.FullName? (when I do this I still get the error..)

Comment: Also change `(attachment)` to `attachment`

Comment: When you save with password are you replacing the existing file or creating a copy ?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my machine and this program worked as it was. If you get a runtime error that is mentioning temporary locations when outlook is involved, you might try restarting your machine.